# Python cProfile - most of time spent in method 'enable' of '_lsprof.Profiler'

Tags: python, cprofile

I am trying to perform some high-level profiling of a rather complex Python program. However, when using cProfile, almost all time is measured in:

`{method 'enable' of '_lsProf.Profiler' objects}`

It happens if I profile the whole program `python -m cProfile ...` as well as when I perform profiling within the Python code (with `profile.enable()/.disable()/.create_stats...`)

Any pointers to what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Hopefully this is useful to some people. I had this issue, which was a result of attempting to profile a generator. Once switching to `return` instead of `yield`, the output file became useful

Answer (score 4):

It's because somewhere in your code you have something like

```
import cProfile
pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()
```

That's for manually saving the results or printing them, if you are calling the profiler like you said with `python -m cProfile -o program.prof my_program.py` you don't need to use cProfile inside the program.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue (at least not clearly to me). I have seen the same thing. Instead of getting a profile of what is being executed I get a single line as mentioned in the original post here. In other words the profiler seems to swallow the stuff it should be profiling.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug or limitation. Nested profilers do not work. here is a repro:

```
import cProfile
import pstats
import time
import cStringIO as StringIO

def do():
    for i in range(100):
       time.sleep(0.01)

def do_more():
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.01)

def do_all():
    all_profiler = cProfile.Profile()
    all_profiler.enable()

    profiler = cProfile.Profile()
    profiler.enable()

    do()

    profiler.disable()
    strio = StringIO.StringIO()
    stats = pstats.Stats(profiler, stream=strio)
    stats.sort_stats("cumulative")
    stats.print_stats(10)
    print "do profile:\n{}".format(strio.getvalue())

    do_more()

    all_profiler.disable()
    strio = StringIO.StringIO()
    stats = pstats.Stats(all_profiler, stream=strio)
    stats.sort_stats("cumulative")
    stats.print_stats(10)
    print "all profile:\n{}".format(strio.getvalue())


do_all()
```

Added to tmp.py and run in the shell, output is:

```sh
do profile:
         103 function calls in 1.009 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    1.009    1.009 tmp.py:6(do)
      100    1.008    0.010    1.008    0.010 {time.sleep}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}



all profile:
         1 function calls in 2.018 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    2.018    2.018    2.018    2.018 {method 'enable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Note the "all_profiler" only shows the other profiler.

EDIT: it is possible this is only an issue with the summary printing. I didn't try dumping the stats to use with a profile viewer like converting for use with kCachegrind, for example.